# How Does Rubymine Work With Remote Interpreters and Git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubymine

I am trying out Rubymine (current version - 6.0.3). My client is Windows and I am connecting to a remote linux host where my Ruby stack is running. I am working on a project that is stored in a git repo so I have cloned the repo both on the Windows client and on the linux box where the project runs.

1. It seems like a downside to have to checkout files locally & remotely separately - am I missing something or is this an unfortunate limitation to Rubymine?
2. How should I create a new branch and have it be the current branch on both the Windows client & the linux server? It seems to me this involves many steps: Create branch locally, push to github, pull to the server, and then checkout that branch. Ouch!

Thanks for any Rubymine tips you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually your local machine should be the only one having to manage the git repository. Use the Deployment (File > Settings > Deployment) feature of IntelliJ (or RubyMine) to keep your server's files up to date by directly uploading them whenever you change and save a file. Set it as default to have it do this automatically.
Adapt the options to your likings as to when it should be uploaded, overwrite settings and so on.

See here for more instructions, although the setup is pretty straightforward:

http://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2011/07/deployment-from-rubymine-sync-files-via-ftpsftp-etc/

You can then access the remote server on a tab on the right hand side. From there, you can download or sync files with your local filesystem with the rightclick menu. You can also upload your local files manually as is usually needed when first setting up a project by rightclicking on your own files to the left.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this helps a lot. How would you get Rubymine back in sync after making new branches/changing branches and changing whatever files on the server side?

Comment: I'd recommend managing the files mostly locally. That means having git only on your local machine. Your server doesn't need to know anything about git. When you switch branches within RubyMine, all the changes are being uploaded to the server automatically. If you really need to change files on the server (maybe after using generation tasks manually), you can use the "Remote Host" tab on the right side of RubyMine. There, you can browse the server and then rightclick the appropriate folder (project root) and select "download". This may override local changes, so beware and use this sparingly

Comment: I don't think I can get away from using the shell on the server to manage branches, etc. I was hoping Rubymine could fit into this but it really needs to handle all or none.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot set up an automatic sync from the server to your local machine as you would need to poll the server all the time to check for changes. After all, the feature is called Deployment, implying the pushing of files to the production environment after developing locally. Git, rake and everything else actually belongs on the development side. That's also the only way for RubyMine to actually help you much more than just a glorified texteditor with sync functionality. You also do have access to a shell/command line of your local OS to do the same actions you now do on your server.